# Can you use a different mapping within another mapping?

Tags: key-bindings

In my _vimrc,
Say I have a keybinding like this:

```
noremap gm f<Space>a{{c<Esc>0ylfcpa::<Esc>A}}<Esc>2F{
```

And another keybinding like this:

```
noremap m3 mckmbkma2j
```

I have tested both in normal Vim and they work fine

At a lower part of the _vimrc file, is it possible to do something like:

```
noremap g3 m3gm
```

I tried this and it doesn't execute properly.

Perhaps there is some kind of substitution I need to do that I'm not aware of. Could someone point me to that concept, if any?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's possible to do what I was trying to do above.

To do so, one needs to understand the difference between noremap and map in Vim.

It works when I use map but not when I use noremap.

map is recursive while noremap is not.

Comment: I would likely use `nnoremap` and `nmap` for Normal-mode only mappings, and you might be interested in `<buffer>` if these are only relevant for a specific filetype